# How to generate multiple json in vertical column in Excel VBA?

Tags: json, excel, vba

Using excel macro The first line is the json file name, and the second and subsequent columns are the values.

With the first column as the key to the json object,
only the values ​​in the second column and only the values ​​in the third column.

How do I generate json in batches in the same directory as the Excel respectively?

For example, column B is the value of column A as a key, the value of column B and b1.json. Column C uses the value of Column A as a key and the value of Column C and c1.json

For example, when the completed json has a description up to column C,

**b1.json**

```
[{
a2: b2,
a3: b3,
a4: b4,
}]
```

**c1.json**

```
[{
a2: c2,
a3: c3,
a4: c4,
}]
```

And want to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is VBA example showing how the files could be created. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/JSON.bas) module from [VBA JSON parser](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) into the VBA project for JSON processing, and include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"** (take a look [here](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser#deployment) how to import module and add reference).

Put the below code in a standard module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        If .Cells.Count < 4 Then
            MsgBox "No data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim source
        source = .Value
    End With
    Dim i
    For i = 2 To UBound(source, 2)
        Dim data
        Set data = New Dictionary
        Dim j
        For j = 2 To UBound(source, 1)
            data(source(j, 1)) = source(j, i)
        Next
        saveTextToFile _
            JSON.Serialize(Array(data)), _
            ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & source(1, i) & ".json", _
            "UTF-8"
    Next
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub saveTextToFile(content, filePath, charset)

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Open
        .charset = charset
        .WriteText content
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' TypeBinary
        .SaveToFile filePath, 2
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

The source data I tested code with:

[image: source]

The output is as follows:

**file1.json**

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "Alice",
        "prop2": "Bob",
        "prop3": "Charlie",
        "prop4": "Eve",
        "prop5": "Dan"
    }
]
```

**file2.json**

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "Tomatoes",
        "prop2": "Bananas",
        "prop3": "Watermelons",
        "prop4": "Apples",
        "prop5": "Grapefruit"
    }
]
```

**file3.json**

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "Russia",
        "prop2": "Canada",
        "prop3": "USA",
        "prop4": "China",
        "prop5": "Brazil"
    }
]
```

*BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).*

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I did the same but got the following compile error.

`new Dictionary`

Comment: **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/JSON.bas) module from [VBA JSON parser](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) into the VBA project for JSON processing, and include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"** (take a look [here](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser#deployment) how to import module and add reference).

Comment: It was impossible on Mac, but made on Windows! !
I wasn't telling my Mac environment, sorry.

Simple English words could be json.

However, character strings containing long Japanese characters or html are described as "error run time error 5 invalid procedure call or argument" and stopped at '.Write JSON.Serialize (Array (data))'

Comment: To make it possible to run on Mac you may use [VBA-Dictionary](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary). Then you have to remove the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Comment: I changed save to file method to support UTF-8 files encoding.

Comment: UTF8 seems to be the cause. Remove Hangul and Polish from Excel and you have a json! Thank you!
If the json file (hoge / fuga.xlsm) with the directory name is in the directory above the Excel file, hogeA1.json will be created. Is it possible to create a json file without a directory name in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact problem I'm having but I can't seem to import the JSON.bas file.  It throws an error saying the file is too complex.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31701482)